# how to fix this problem in HTML CSS BOOTSTRAP?

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image]I have an issue that is driving me CRAZY at the moment /// 
I have made this page with HTML CSS & BOOTSTRAP 4 // everything was working well
as you can see in the image below, I wrote a paragraph and it went well, save the document // 
came back later to add more text to the paragraph and as you can see !! it's now leaving the div and keeps growing across the browser ??? What is this ? going crazy here ! 
I was able to put as much text as I wanted to before this happened ! and now this happens in every div in the page..

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <center>
                        <h2 class="h2-lg-light">Hi :)</h2>
                    </center>

                </div>
                <div class="[![enter image description here][1]][1]col-lg-7">
                    <P>My name is <font color="000"><b>Mohamed NAGY</b></font>. Having a passion for creating flawless web applications has led me into the web design and development profession. I'm obsessed with creating memorable online experiences, and I'm most satisfied when I see my work run flawlessly online across all platforms. in addition to having a bachelor's degree in software development, I'm also self-taught trough books, and many hours and practice and production. ###############################################################################################################################################################################################

                    </P>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

Add the following css class to the style.

```
<head>
    <style>
        .limit-text {
            word-break: break-word;
            white-space: pre-line;
            /* max-width: 100%; */
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Add the css class "limit-text" to your div (this will break your long text to next line when max-width of the div reached).

```
<div class="[![enter image description here][1]][1]col-lg-7 limit-text">
                <P>My name is <font color="000"><b>Mohamed NAGY</b></font>. Having a passion for creating flawless web applications has led me into the web design and development profession. I'm obsessed with creating memorable online experiences, and I'm most satisfied when I see my work run flawlessly online across all platforms. in addition to having a bachelor's degree in software development, I'm also self-taught trough books, and many hours and practice and production. ###############################################################################################################################################################################################

                </P>
            </div>
```

Comment: BRO !!!!!!!!! I just realized that this happens only if I type with NO SPACE // for example: ############ .. but if I do ### ### ### / it goes right in place!! very weird

Comment: But we have to eliminate all possible chance of these kind of design breaking stuff. Don't expect this will not happen and no need to worry. If user can enter text then we cannot tell him to put space between sentences.

Comment: could it be something with bootstrap ?? I have now idea why this happens !!

Comment: @Vipin answer is correct, if you are satisfied with an answer please make it as a correct answer.